# "Taylor series" and "proof of Euler's formula"

Tags: calculus

I have learned that we can prove Euler's formula by using Taylor series, as shown on wiki:
[Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).

I have a question.
As [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) says:
In mathematics, a Taylor series is a representation of a function as an infinite sum of terms that are calculated from the values of the function's derivatives at **a single point**.

Since Taylor series is only the expression of a function at a single point. 
And the first proof of [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) is using the Taylor Series at point 0. Why it can be used to prove Euler's Formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor series (the *formula*) depends only from the values of the function's derivatives at a single point ($a$ is fixed). But the Taylor series (the *function*) is a... function and depends of a variable ($x$ varies).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I spent several days studying and now I almost understand it. But I still have a question, is there any sense in terms of geometry or physics. Because it is quite difficult for me to understand a function,which is periodic such as sin(x), can be expressed by a bunch of polynomials.

Comment: @Dongguo, any approximation of $\sin$ by a polynomial is good only in a finite interval. See the diagram in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series.